# Saving products in script

Tags: product

When saving products in magento through custom scripts I have always had to add the following:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Otherwise you get a wierd error from eav/config model about an invalid argument foreach.

Can anyone explain why products can only be saved under the admin store id? and if this code i have been using is in fact the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When saving a product the call stack reaches  `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_collectSaveData()`. In this method you loop through the `_origData` member of the model and get the attributes that are different and save only those ones.
The `_origData` member is populated when loading a model by calling `setOrigData()`.
So far so good. The difference is that for the product model the method `setOrigData()` looks like this (for performance reasons I assume):

```
public function setOrigData($key=null, $data=null)
{
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return parent::setOrigData($key, $data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This means that if you are not in the admin environment `_origData` will be `null`.
In this case `_collectSaveData()` tries to loop through `null`, thus the error you are getting.