# After Update product attribute, vanishes tier prices

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I tried to update product's attribute called barcode as follows.

It update the product but cleared tier price of that product. Please help me.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $prod_sku);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

if ($product) {
  $product->setBarcode($bar_code);
  if(! $product->save()){
            $productId = $product->getId();
            echo "product_Id :: ".$productId." - Product sku :: ".$product->getSku()."<br />";
        }else{
            echo "not saved";
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($prod_sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
if ($product) {
  $product->setBarcode($bar_code);
  if(! $product->save()){
            $productId = $product->getId();
            echo "product_Id :: ".$productId." - Product sku :: ".$product->getSku()."<br />";
        }else{
            echo "not saved";
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. It works fine. Can you please explain the purpose of setting ADMIN_STORE_ID?

Comment: @cha This should explain it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5246/146

Comment: When I'm updating products I got this error. Can you help me on this.. ======Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`)' in /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: And also====
Stack trace: #0 /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/path/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', A in /home/path/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

Comment: Most probably you are trying to set an attribute_set_id that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess.

Try using `load($prod_sku, 'sku')` instead of `loadByAttribute('sku', $prod_sku)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it gives object. But saving functionality not working.

Comment: Please check Marius answer. It works for me.